# Application Design - Validation and efficiency

Tags: c#, architecture

I have an ASP.Net application which has a lot of business rules with regards to if an object is OK to be commited to the database.

On a basic level, a person is part of a sprint, which is part of a project.

The basic rules are:

A person is assigned to a sprint, but maybe not the full duration of a sprint (Which has a start and end date). So, when they assign the person, his start date and end date must be between (inclusivly) the start and end date of a sprint.

A project can have many sprints, but none can be outside of the project start/end dates.

My solution has a UI project, Service layer, business layer and data access layer.

I am building in the validation now, but am not sure at what level in my app, the calidation should occur. I don't believe it's at the UI, as then I need to duplciate the validation rules on my ASP.Net project ... maybe my WinForms front end...

I think it should be in the busines logic, as it has business rules. So, I was going to make a class called "Validations", and for each of my business objects that get stored to the database, I have a method in my Validations called "IsObjectOK", taking in the object type I want to validate, and returning a List of errors.

So:

```
public List<String> IsObjectOK(SprintDto source)
{
    // Do validations, and return list of errors, or NULL if none
}
```

An example then of a validation rule might be:

```
var Project = BusinessLayer.GetProject(source.ProjectId);
// check if Start/End dates fall between Project.Start and Project.End dates
```

If there's an issue, add it to the error list.

This seems like a good way to go. I am looking for confirmation on my method of handling validation, and any tips and tricks? Should I not worry about the database hits? I mean, for a sprint, there may be around 6 or 7 'rules' I need to validate, all of which may take data from different tables. So, that's 7 database queries (Plus the connection overhead), for a single save. (SQL Server 2012). I think that's not a worry, as it's all confided to the Business and data layers.

Comment: The technique is depends, are you doing CI, singleton, or Command pattern (CQRS), are you using ORM? However, it should be on Business Layer, and 7 call to database will surely make a bad performance on high volume app.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about the database hits until you have to.  There are lots of ways to optimize that *after* you get your architecture right.  A good caching layer will make most of those go away, and if not, you could always write a separate domain object that is the "SprintValidation" object to contain all the data you need to validate it.

Don't start by compromising your architecture for performance until you know it's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

When there's possibility for an object to become inconsistent, I always try to create barriers to prevent that, as early and as firmly as possible.

**Early**

Ideally, an object in an incoherent state shouldn't even reach layers above the UI. A date interval is typically something you can easily check on the client side when creating or modifying a Sprint. The user will appreciate the immediate feedback on what went wrong or is not possible (greyed out button for instance), and double insurance is always nice. It might not be the feasible with more complex verifications though.

**Firmly**

In the business, try to model those rules as *invariants* that are enforced once, rather than *validations* you may need to perform multiple times. In other terms, make sure that your business objects are [always valid](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2009/05/22/always-valid/).

- Enforce invariants upon creation (in constructor or Factory) and make your objects immutable [Value Objects](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html) whenever you can. PersonAssignment in your example is a good candidate to that. Value Objects are simple structures you never bother to modify, you only replace them with another one, so keeping them always consistent is a piece of cake.
- For objects you can't sensibly make entirely immutable (such as a Sprint), you can still filter out unwanted modification of certain fields. For instance, modify the setters for properties StartDate and EndDate to not accept dates that are outside the Project range.
- Sometimes, business rules associated with a state change are more complex and involve many conditionals. I found it is always better to define the business operation in a single method and incorporate all invariant checking there rather than let your entity go in a broken state and try to verify it afterwards.

In short : narrow down opportunities for modification to a few places and don't hesitate to perform strict enforcement there, so that you can then rely on confidence rather than suspicion.